# How can I assign previously declared variables based on pattern matching?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Say I have some code of the sort:

```scala
var (nodes, d, p) = someFunction()
```

Then I have a few more instructions and I need to refresh the values of nodes, d and p. My current code is something like

```scala
val aux = someFunction(); nodes = aux._1; d = aux._2; p = aux._3
```

Which is obviously unnecessarily ugly. Ideally I'd want to do something like

```
(nodes, d, p) = someFunction()
```

Where the variables have been already declared before, but Scala doesn't allow me.

Any ideas on how to "solve" this?

Comment: If you need mutability _(which you shouldn't)_ then use `vars` instead of `vals`. Now, I wouldn't be surprised if the extractor syntax doesn't work with `vars` since it is good for a language that embraces immutability to make mutable code to look bad.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I need mutability in my context and I did indeed have vars, sorry for the mistake. I've edited my post now. A simple example is that `var x = 1; var y = 1; (x, y) = (1, 2)` does not work

Comment: _"I need mutability in my context"_ I am pretty sure you do not need it, you only believe you need it because you have been educated to be mutable. Been there done that, the only way to stop feeling mutability is necessary is to force yourself using it. - In any case, that is slightly opinionated from my part and somewhat off-topic. The answer to your question is, AFAIK, not possible; again the language was made to favour immutability it is not surprising that this kind of syntax doesn't work for `vars`.

Comment: Why not just declaring new variables and working with them? `val (nodes1, d1, p1) = someFunction() /* use nodes1, d1, p1 */ val (nodes2, d2, p2) = someFunction() /* use nodes2, d2, p2 */`

Answer (score 1):

You can write a helper function in the local context that takes the tuple that is returned from `someFunction()` and mutate needed variables.
Like this:

```
def someEnclosingFunctionOrCodeBlock = {
  var nodes, d, p;
  def mutateVars(tuple: (TypeNodes, TypeD, TypeP)): Unit = {
    nodes = tuple._1
    d = tuple._2
    p = tuple._3
  }
  mutateVars(someFunction())
  // ..
  mutateVars(someFunction())
}
```

Additionally, you can fold it into 1 function that is something like `callSomeFunctionAndMutateVars()`.
You can do it 2 ways - using the previous helper function

```
def callSomeFunctionAndMutateVars() = mutateVars(someFunction())
```

Or changing the previous helper function to

```
def callSomeFunctionAndMutateVars(): Unit = {
    val tuple = someFunction()
    nodes = tuple._1
    d = tuple._2
    p = tuple._3
}
```

PS: Honestly, you should consider changing it to immutable structures and an explicit composition of evaluations.

Comment: The variables are still mutable.

Comment: Yes, and it was completely intentional. So? didn't get what are you trying to suggest. The topic starter says "I need mutability in my context".